# Azure AD Misconfigured Application Error AADSTS650056 Using Enterprise ServiceNow Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have received the below error while configuring ServiceNow SSO. I have configured this previously on other instances of ServiceNow. I used the auto configuration from the Azure AD portal to configure ServiceNow. Configuration is identical to the previous configuration. I vaguely remember that I had to consent for this app to be used, but grant admin consent is disabled under the Enterprise App > ServiceNow App > Permissions.

Am I missing something here?

> AADSTS650056: Misconfigured application. This could be due to one of
> the following: the client has not listed any permissions for 'AAD
> Graph' in the requested permissions in the client's application
> registration. Or, the admin has not consented in the tenant. Or, check
> the application identifier in the request to ensure it matches the
> configured client application identifier. Or, check the certificate in
> the request to ensure it's valid. Please contact your admin to fix the
> configuration or consent on behalf of the tenant.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve that error, please find below suggestions if they are helpful:

- Please check the **[prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/servicenow-tutorial#prerequisites)** before integrating **Azure AD SSO** with **ServiceNow.**
- Please note that you should enable the **multi-provider plugin for ServiceNow** if you are selecting ***auto-configuration.***

To know how to enable that option, please follow below steps if they are helpful:

- Login to your **ServiceNow** instance using admin credentials.
- To activate multi-provider SSO plugin, follow below steps:

***Search for the System Definition -> Select Plugins -> Search for Integration - Multiple Provider single sign-on Installer -> Select Activate/Upgrade -> Activate***

- To enable multi-provider SSO plugin, follow below steps:

***Search for the Multi-Provider SSO-> Properties -> Select 'Yes' for all properties -> Save as below:***

[image]

- Copy your ServiceNow instance URL,
  ***Go to Azure AD -> Enterprise Applications -> ServiceNow -> SSO -> Basic SAML configuration***
- Replace **`Identifier URL`** value with the copied URL of ServiceNow instance.

> **Make sure that the **`Issuer`** attribute in the SAML request matches the **`Identifier`** value configured in Azure AD.**

To know more in detail, please find below **links** if they are helpful.

[Error AADSTS650056 - Misconfigured application - Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts650056-misconfigured-app#:%7E:text=This%20article%20describes%20a%20problem%20in%20which%20you,The%20admin%20has%20not%20consented%20in%20the%20tenant.)

[Tutorial: Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with ServiceNow | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/servicenow-tutorial#configure-servicenow)